# Rewrite part of the example code from Adafruit FONA

Tags: arduino-uno

Recently, I bought the FONA 800 shield from Adafruit. I have got it running with the examples and it plays very nicely.

I want to use the part of the example code which handles a call in my own sketch. The example code waits for a number to call which should be entered in the serial. I want to do the exact same thing, just with the phone number supplied from a variable in Arduino.

I have two possibilities: To supply the whole number when the call should be performed and to build up let's say an array every time a number is entered.

The code for performing a call:

```
// call a phone!
    char number[30];
    flushSerial();
    Serial.print(F("Call #"));
    readline(number, 30);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("Calling ")); Serial.println(number);
    if (!fona.callPhone(number)) {
      Serial.println(F("Failed"));
    } else {
      Serial.println(F("Sent!"));
    }
```

The flushSerial function:

```
void flushSerial() {
  while (Serial.available())
  Serial.read();
}
```

And the readline function:

```
uint8_t readline(char *buff, uint8_t maxbuff, uint16_t timeout) {
uint16_t buffidx = 0;
boolean timeoutvalid = true;
if (timeout == 0) timeoutvalid = false;

while (true) {
  if (buffidx > maxbuff) {
    //Serial.println(F("SPACE"));
    break;
  }

while (Serial.available()) {
  char c =  Serial.read();

  //Serial.print(c, HEX); Serial.print("#"); Serial.println(c);

  if (c == '\r') continue;
  if (c == 0xA) {
    if (buffidx == 0)   // the first 0x0A is ignored
      continue;

    timeout = 0;         // the second 0x0A is the end of the line
    timeoutvalid = true;
    break;
  }
  buff[buffidx] = c;
  buffidx++;
}

if (timeoutvalid && timeout == 0) {
  //Serial.println(F("TIMEOUT"));
  break;
}
  delay(1);
}
  buff[buffidx] = 0;  // null term
  return buffidx;
}
```

It is the readline function which should be edited. Right now it retrieves the number entered from serial.

I am kind of a newbie myself so I am not that familiar with data types and so on.

Thank you very much for any answers.

EDIT: 
The function without readline:

```
if (!fona.callPhone("12345678")) {
        Serial.println(F("Failed calling"));
      } else {
        Serial.println(F("Calling ..."));
      }
```

Comment: I can't quite follow this. The much obvious way to make this use a constant phone number this would be to load your number string into the `char number[30];` variable and skip the entire `readline` process. You could also simple substitute `char* number = "01234567..";`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt
That's the problem. I can't just put in a number, it fails calling. As I wrote, I am not that familiar with Arduino but I think it wants the numbers as an array or something (that's why I gave you the readline function). I have tried a various ways to put in the number directly to the call function but none of the times did it go well.

Comment: All `readline` does is fill the `number` buffer with the data coming over serial while ignoring newlines. If you input some number "1234" over serial then it **is** equivalent to just putting `char* number = "1234";`. Are you absolutely sure that if you input the number over serial using `readline` it works, but putting the same number directly in the `number` variable doesn't? Can you show the code with which you tried that?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt
This is what I have tried. If it is a number it doesn't even recognize the number. When it is a string like here it inputs the number correctly but somehow it fails calling (I have done exactly as I did when it worked regarding the way I call the call function)

Comment: When calling through the shield, it prints in the serial (the library does). I can see the number it is trying to call which is only correct when I put in the numbers as a string. But the next serial print is the one I have defined to tell if there is an error: "Failed calling".

Comment: I see no logical reason why this should not work. Please post the *entire* code which is trying to call a hard-coded number and also the serial monitor output. If `ARDUINO_FONA_DEBUG` is defined in your library ([here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FONA/blob/master/includes/FONAConfig.h)), you should see at least some more debug messages on what it's trying to do. What is the serial debug output compared to when you input it over `Serial` with the first version?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, thank you so much for the help. I was confused about the string, numbers, buffers and so on which were the course for it to fail. It works now. Please leave an answer for closing this question

Comment: i think it's best if you write the answer yourself because I'm not sure what exactly you changed in the code so that it suddenly runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enter the numbers as a string. Also I found out that I had set the variables in a wrong way.

The library for the FONA Shield needs the number to call as a string. They are creating it by assigning the input from serial to a char. 
The problem was that I tried to input numbers. Also, I found out that when I tried to work with variables instead of hard coded numbers I messed around in data types.

Final conclusion: 
When calling the fona.callPhone function, you have to put in a string containing the numbers instead of actual numbers.

Comment: Of course. I can't mark my own as correct before 22 hours have passed ..